# Editar row.names en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando editar el nombre de filas en un Dataframe con `dplyr str_split` en R, tengo nombres largos y me interesa solo obtener nombres en especifico, así:

```
miRNA_ENSG00000278267.1__17369__17399 ### este es el formato que tengo de nombres de filas

ENSG00000278267.1 ### Esta parte es la que necesito extraer como nombre de fila
```

He intentado sacando los `row.names` a un objeto y después usar `str_split` para separar lo que no necesito pero no he tenido éxito

```
g <- str_split(row.names(x), "miRNA_") ### aca puedo separar la primera parte del nombre
g <- str_split(g, "__")## Al tratar de separar por los caracteres especiales __ y me hecho un lio
```

He intentado con `strsplit` y no me ha funcionado,

Alguien puede sugerirme por favor como limpiar mi `rownames` como lo necesito

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple es usar el guión bajo como separador y quedarse con la segunda palabra, puedes aplicar esto con `sapply()` para obtener un vector los recortes deseados:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1)
rownames(df) <- 'miRNA_ENSG00000278267.1__17369__17399'

nombres <- sapply(rownames(df),
                  FUN=function(x) strsplit(x, '_')[[1]][2]
                  )
```

Ten en cuenta que los `rownames` no pueden repetirse